# Remove space from the variable in php

Tags: php

In the below code $val whatever value you enter in the text box it is taking a space for example
$val="6 " or $val="abc  " Below is my simple code

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'][$i] as $key => $val)

     {
         if($key=="company_name")
         {
             $company_name_session=$val;
         }
         elseif($key=="product_name")
         {
             $product_name_session=$val;

         }
         else if($key=="unit")
         {
             $unit_session=$val;

         }
         else if($key=="packing_size")
         {
             $packing_size_session=$val;

         }
         else if($key=="qty")
         {
             $qty_session=$val;

         }

         else if($key=="price")
         {
             $price_session=$val;

         }

     }
```

My Question is how to remove this space while declaring a variable in php .

Comment: [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it

Comment: but not only here i am getting space in every variable . is there any way t declare a variable with no space.

Comment: You can overwrite its value at the begining of the loop : `$val = trim($val);`

Comment: this `if/elseif/else if` madness.... ( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°) use `switch/case` instead

Answer (score 1):

[trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) should do it, if you're interested in removing the **spaces around the text**.

```
 $val = trim($val);
```

You could also use the [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php), which **trims the end**.

Or if you wanted to remove **all** spaces in the variables, you could use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$val = str_replace(' ', '', $val);
```

Edit:
And as [Nathaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199368/nathanael) mentioned, you can also use `preg_replace()`, if you want to use regular expressions for more complex rules.

Comment: if you need anything more advanced you can use `preg_replace()`